# Why Python doesnt append correctly from cursor

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to understand Python list.append() when looping through a cursor.
For example, I have a cursor that contains [(itemA,valA),(itemB,valB)]

```
for item in cursor.fetchall():
    # error doesnt show the correct values
    posts_dict["title"] = item[0]
    posts_dict["description"] = item[1]
    posts_list.append(posts_dict)
```

-> results in posts_list -> [(itemB,valB),(itemB,valB)]

But if I'm using list comprehension I get the correct values.

```
for item in cursor.fetchall():
    posts_list.append(dict(title=row[0], description=row[1]))
```

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: can you show what is in posts_dict

Comment: As a side note, many DB-API 2 modules have a way to get a dict-like or namedtuple-like row type instead of a plain list, which might make this code completely irrelevant; just `posts_list.extend(cursor.fetchall())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep reusing `posts_dict`, so you add the same object twice.

```
for item in cursor.fetchall():
  posts_dict = {}
  posts_dict["title"] = item[0]
  posts_dict["description"] = item[1]
  posts_list.append(posts_dict)
```

Or even better:

```
for item in cursor.fetchall():
  posts_dict = {"title": item[0], "description": item[1]}
  posts_list.append(posts_dict)
```